# Normalizing an Orthogonal Set of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, orthogonality, orthonormal

I've been given the basis $B=\{(1,-1),(1,-2)\}$ and am asked to find the orthonormal basis using the Gram-Schmidt process. No problem! I have the orthogonal set of vectors $w_1 = (1,-1)$ and $w_2 = (\frac{-1}{2},\frac{-1}{2})$ meaning $||w_1|| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $ and $||w_2|| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $.

In making these into an orthonormal set of vectors however, I am to arrive at $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,-1)\}$. How is $(\frac{-1}{2},\frac{-1}{2})$ becoming $(-1,-1)$? Clearly I'm missing something obvious... Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You divide the vector by its length to get a vector (in the same direction) of length 1. That's what normalizing means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Correct, which is how I get 1/√2 (−1/2, −1/2) yet the answer is given to be 1/√2 (−1, −1).

Comment: What you get doesn't have length 1 – try it! I think you multiplied by $1/\sqrt2$, instead of dividing by it. (But I see @amd has already explained this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gerry Myerson points out, you *divide* by the norm to produce a unit vector. $\|w_1\|=\sqrt2$, not $1/\sqrt2$. When you divide $w_1$ by this you get $\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,-1)$ for the first vector as before. $\|w_2\|=1/\sqrt2$. Again, you *divide* $w_2$ by this value, giving $\sqrt2(-1/2,-1/2)=\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,-1)$ for the second.

Comment: Thank you! I see I was not only jumbling my vocab but my figures as well. Appreciate the help. This is why I shouldn't do math at night...